# How do I set up a small Terminal Server, with both the Server and Terminals running Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, server, client, terminal-server

I would like to set up a Terminal server and connect 4 or 5 "terminals" running Ubuntu desktop for a small school. In functional terms, I'd like the students to be able to log on to their accounts from any machine, using a username and password.

I'm a real newbie at networking, but I've been using Ubuntu for several years and I have a programming background.

**Where should I begin?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you only need centralized accounting, or do the students also need to get a personal home directory mapped? For the former, PAM and some authentication server (Radius/LDAP/etc) is required. The latter requires either NFS or some smb setup.

Comment: Thanks.  The students need to be able to login and see their file space from any machine.  I guess NFS is the way to go?  What is NFS :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I would recommend a solution based on LDAP for authentication and user management, and NFS for storage.

In the following, I assume that by "Terminals" you do not mean X server forwarding, but actual local sessions. For actual terminal servers the server runs the applications, and the client simply displays the "GUI". More info on that setup [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP).

That also reminds me: [Edubuntu](https://www.edubuntu.org/) might be worth a look for you.

**User management**

You need a centralized database to store usernames and passwords. LDAP is one solution for that. It is a database running on your server, and the clients use the linux PAM architecture to connect to it for authentication.

[How to set up LDAP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication)

**Storage**

NFS is a network file system. Simplified, this means that you can mount it over the network, just like a local partition. In a nutshell, it is similar to smb, the windows "shared drives" protocol. In your case, you would mount the user's home directory from the central NFS server after login.

[How to set up NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)